# Getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException while copy between two Datagridviews

Tags: c#

If somebody could please help solve the following issue:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Paarameter name
>   : index

The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView3.Rows.Count; j++)
   {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["supplier_name"].Value as string) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells["brands_supplier"].Value as string))
      {
         if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["supplier_name"].Value.ToString() == dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells["brands_supplier"].Value.ToString())
         {                                   
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["brands_name"].Value += dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells["brands_nume"].Value + " ";
         }
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access an element of your datagrid which doesn't exist.
You have to set your `for` condition to

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

and

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; j++)
```

don't use `<=` because the index of `dataGridView.Rows[]` is 0 based.

For example, if your datagrid contains 3 elements you can reach them with:

```
var row1 = dataGrid.Rows[0]
var row2 = dataGrid.Rows[1]
var row3 = dataGrid.Rows[2]
```

And you try to access

```
var row4 = dataGrid.Rows[3]  // Error because this item doesn't exist (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
```

also, but this item doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in cycle

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

You run one more time

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
```